# Android emulator is not working on Linux because of libGL

Tags: android, kvm-virtualization, android-emulator

I used a few Linux distros (Ubuntu, Deepin, etc.) and I'm using KDE Neon User Edition at the moment. When I want to use Android emulator, I can't. Because Android emulator isn't run on all Linux distros for me.
**Info**: My outputs:

```
user@username-PC:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ ./emulator -accel-check
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
accel
user@username-PC:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ kvm-ok 
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
user@username-PC:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
4
```

When I start the Android emulator, I get this error:

```
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  58
  Current serial number in output stream:  59
```

When I set Multi-core CPU setting as 1:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  58
  Current serial number in output stream:  59
```

When I change Graphics setting as Software - GLES 2.0 (default: Automatic), I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using system libstdc++ solves the issue**

For example:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools
./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -use-system-libs
```

If it works correctly, set the following variable in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
```

Re-login or `source ~.bashrc`. You can then omit the `-use-system-libs` option:

```
./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27
```

This method does not work when the emulator is called from Android Studio. Here is a workaround

Create a shell script `android-studio.sh` in a directory available in your `PATH`. For example `~/bin` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
~/Programs/android-studio/bin/studio.sh %f
```

and then update the launcher command in

```
~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop
```

to point to `~/bin/android-studio.sh`.